Edit the behavior of a button using Tampermonkey


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#spectate').accesskey = 'k';
});
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium main-btns css-1hw9j7s" tabindex="0" type="button" id="spectate" style="background-color: rgb(244, 67, 54); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 2px solid rgb(244, 67, 54); padding: 10px 20px; font-size: 16px; cursor: pointer; width: 150px; height: 200px;">
  <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
  Spectate
  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span>
</button>



I'm trying to add accesskey="k" to the button, so that when pressing Alt+K it is pressed.
I have searched on the internet how to edit the behavior of a button using Tampermonkey but all I could find is information on how to create a new button. Could you help me?
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium main-btns css-1hw9j7s" tabindex="0" type="button" id="spectate" style="background-color: rgb(244, 67, 54); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 2px solid rgb(244, 67, 54); padding: 10px 20px; font-size: 16px; cursor: pointer; width: 150px; height: 200px;">
  <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
  Spectate
  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span>
</button>


That button already has the accesskey="k" attribute...?

You're right, I was testing and accidentally copied the button code with the "accesskey" already added, thanks for the correction and edit!

To do what you require, select the #spectate element from the DOM and set its accessKey property as required. Note that you will need to do this after the DOM has loaded, hence the DOMContentLoaded event handler in the following example:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#spectate').accessKey = 'k';
});
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium main-btns css-1hw9j7s" tabindex="0" type="button" id="spectate" style="background-color: rgb(244, 67, 54); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 2px solid rgb(244, 67, 54); padding: 10px 20px; font-size: 16px; cursor: pointer; width: 150px; height: 200px;">
  <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
  Spectate
  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span>
</button>



Also note that your example HTML already has the accesskey="k" attribute within it - I'm going to assume this is a mistake in the question.

I'm a newbie trying to learn all this, some things I can say may be inconsistent, English is not my language either so I have to translate.
Try running the command from Tampermonkey after the page loads, even from the console, but the "accesskey" attribute is not added to the button's behavior.

Without a specific example of the context you're running this under, it's going to be almost impossible to debug. Because, as you can see above, this code works fine.

In your example, you already have the "accesskey" attribute added to the button's behavior. When you add your solution in javascript, the button's behavior remains the same. I didn't know where to project the code, so I added it to the question.

You're right - I copied the HTML from your original which also included the attribute by default. If you run my updated version, with the HTML changed to remove the accesskey attribute, you can see it's been added by JS instead. You can check this with the DOM inspector.

It turned out perfect, thank you very much for everything!
